# What type of power outlets should I expect in hotels in Sao Paulo and Rio de Janeiro?

Tags: electronic-items, brazil, power

From my the information I have read on Internet, it seems like Brazil covers a good part of the alphabet when it comes to power outlet types.

What type of power outlets should I expect in hotels in Sao Paulo and Rio de Janeiro?

Comment: @Karlson thanks but they seem to say there are two type of plugs and don't really answer the more specific questions of hotels in Sao Paulo and Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: How would this be answered any more specifically unless someone goes to the specific hotel you're referring to and take a picture of  the outlets they have installed?  Best you can do is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Brazilian_standard_NBR_14136_.28Type_N.29

Comment: Besides you're unlikely to encounter a need for a 3 prong plug unless you bring a fridge or similar with you.

Comment: @Karlson Thanks for the link. My computers' chargers are 3 prong plugs. The linked answers failed to give a good idea of the mainstream use in hotels.

Comment: You're bringing your desktop(s)?

Comment: @Karlson laptops and monitors.

Comment: Most laptops don't need and don't provide a grounded (3 prong) plug and none of them need 20A power outlet to run.

Comment: @Karlson I agree that it is not a requirement but I'm afraid I won't be able to plug my charge plug to the wall plug.

Comment: Then why not just call up the hotel and ask them what kind of plugs they have?  There isn't really a way for anyone to answer the question any more specifically then the one I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Karlson I guess that this is what I'm going to do (or more likely just call a friend who lives there). I'm going to several different hotels so calling each of them is not so convenient. I simply wanted to know whether hotels all provide the same type of power outlets or different ones, in which case then I can call to know the specifics of each hotel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2009, in a not smart act, the brazilian governament created a new standard that's **different from all other countries in the world:**

[image: why did they do it?]

This image shows the brazillian standard at the bottom and the number of countries (*países*, in red) that use each other standard.

That said, it is still very common to find the american standard (second one) and mainly the "universal" plug (last one). Actually the most common is to find a plug using the universal without the ground port, so you'd need an adapter anyway.

Post 2009 buildings are **required** to use the new standard, while older buildings were not required to change existing plugs, so it doesn't depend on where you go (São Paulo/Rio or the rest), but when the hotel was created/renovated.

That is such a hassle that every hotel must be prepared to have adapters for their guests, I wouldn't worry if I my things use the american standard, but I guess I would buy one adapter to the american or universal or brazilian standard if using the other standards.

Comment: Is there a universal standard at all? I believe not.

Comment: wait, the european standard is used by *45%* of the world's population, in over 100 countries!? I've travelled a fair bit and I can't recall having seen it outside of Europe... where are these countries that make up that massive proportion? A bit of googling suggests a lot of African countries use it - anyone know?

Comment: @techpacker South Korea uses the same plug as France.

Comment: Israel also has a unique three prong shape.

What I find least pleasant about the Brasil standard is I don't think my "universal" adapter will do it.

Comment: [Brazil's NBR 14136 is derived from the future standard and compatible with the Europlug (CEE 7/16).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60906-1#Brazilian_NBR_14136_standard)